# How I can convert a variable from hex to dec in C++?

Tags: c++, hex

I want to convert a variable from hex to dec. I know the solution with 'cout', but I don't want to display the variable. How can I do this?

```
int checksum = 98 (HEX value)
```

Comment: @rak007 the question is hex to decimal.

Comment: @PaulFloyd Did you even read the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that 98 is a hexadecimal number, and you write it in source code:

```
int checksum=0x98; // checksum is going to be 152
```

Answer (score 1):

The `98` literal is not a hexadecimal literal, it's a decimal literal representing an integer value of 98. If you prepend it with a hexadecimal prefix of `0x` then the literal represents a decimal value of`152`:

```
int checksum = 0x98; // which is 152 in base 10 number system
```

Values are values, whether represented by decimal, hexadecimal, octal or even binary [literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). Ultimately it's all bytes in memory. The value remains the same and of type `int`. Only the representation of that value can be manipulated whether through stream manipulators or literals. Excerpt from a hexadecimal literal reference:

> hex-literal is the character sequence 0x or the character sequence 0X
>   followed by one or more hexadecimal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
>   9, a, A, b, B, c, C, d, D, e, E, f, F)